# how to animate an item on selection in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a list of cateogories in gridview build...

when i tap item of gridview items.. i want to replace at 0 index and want a bit animation so that it highlights the change

i hve done swaping coding but need to animation.. so that user can see the changes...

i dont want simple animation like border of circle avtar effect or blinking circle avtar...

```
Scaffold(
      body: Center(child:
       Column(
         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
         children: [
         Container(
           height: 200,
           width: 300,
           child: GridView.builder(
             physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
             shrinkWrap: true,
             gridDelegate:
             const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                 crossAxisCount: 5,
                 mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                 crossAxisSpacing: 4.0),
             itemCount: categories.length,
             itemBuilder: (context, index) {
               final category=categories[index];

               return InkWell(
                   onTap: (){
                     setState(() {
                       selected=category;
                       String temp=categories[0];
                       categories[0]=selected!;
                       categories[index]=temp;
                     });
                   },
                   child: CircleAvatar(child: Text(category),));
             },
           ),
         ),
         SizedBox(height: 20,),
         if(selected!=null)Text(selected!,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),),
       ],),),
    )
```